# Database connection problem and api calls

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGesx.png)

I am not able to connect my database and getting this problem when i run any api call in postman ,I have tried so many  things but not able to get it out .

Comment: can you share your server.js file?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because

1. The MongoDB service isn't started.

> Start MongoDB:  `sudo systemctl start mongod`
>
> Verify that MongoDB has started successfully: `sudo systemctl status mongod`

2. The port is already serving some service.

> Find pid: `lsof -i:27017`
>
> Kill pid: `kill -9 pid`

3. Your connection string is incorrect

> mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp');

4. Your localhost is not configured to use mongoDB

Answer (score 0):

```js
const app=require("./app");
const dotenv=require("dotenv");
const connectDatabase=require("./config/database");
PORT=4000;

//Handling uncaught Exception(YouTube Wala Error)
process.on("uncaughtException",(err)=>{
    console.log(`Error:${err.message}`);
    console.log(`Shuting Down the server due to uncaught Exception`);
    process.exit(1);
})




// config
// dotenv.config({path:"backend/config/config.env"});


//Connecting to database
connectDatabase();

const server=app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
})

   



//Unhandled Promise Rejection-> in case when we use mongo(using)
process.on("unhandledRejection",err=>{
    console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
    console.log(`Shuting Down the server due to Unhandled Promise Rejection`);

    server.close(() =>{ 
   process.exit(1);
    })
})
```